Case-insensitive UniqueConstraint using SQLAlchemy with PostgreSQL DB
I am using SQLAlchemy and PostgreSQL, and I am trying to create a case-insensitive unique constraint that works like this
        UniqueConstraint(
            'country',
            'organisation_id',
            func.lower(func.trim('name')),
            name='uq_country_orgid_lower_trim_name'
        )

Ensuring a unique combination of name, country and organisation id, regardless of case and spacing in the name, i.e. "Name 1", "name1", "nAmE    1" would all be handled as "name1" in the check.
I want to make sure that I do not change the actual case or spacing of the name saved in the database.
How would I go about this?

I would do DDL directly in the database, rather than through third-party libraries. ORMs are great for DML, but DDL has too many bells and whistles.

This is mostly the ORM version of @snakecharmerb and avoids the use of text (nothing wrong with sanitized text, it is just a preference). This answer suggests using a unique index, instead of unique constraint because SQLA lacks support.
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, func, Index, select, column
from sqlalchemy.exc import IntegrityError
from sqlalchemy.orm import DeclarativeBase, Mapped, mapped_column, Session

class Base(DeclarativeBase): ...

class SomeTable(Base):
    __tablename__ = "some_table"
    __table_args__ = (
        Index(
            "uq_country_orgid_lower_trim_name",
            "country",
            "organization_id",
            func.lower(func.replace(column("name"), " ", "")),
            unique=True,
        ),
    )
    name: Mapped[str]
    id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(primary_key=True)
    country: Mapped[str]
    organization_id: Mapped[int]

engine = create_engine("postgresql+psycopg://")
Base.metadata.create_all(engine)

with Session(engine) as session:
    session.add(SomeTable(country="C1", organization_id=1, name="NAME 1"))
    session.commit()

with Session(engine) as session:
    rows = (
        SomeTable(country="C1", organization_id=1, name="NAME1"),
        SomeTable(country="C1", organization_id=1, name="Name 1"),
        SomeTable(country="C1", organization_id=1, name="name1"),
        SomeTable(country="C1", organization_id=1, name="nAmE 1"),
    )
    for row in rows:
        try:
            with session.begin_nested():
                session.add(row)
        except IntegrityError:
            print("failed as expected")

with Session(engine) as session:
    row = session.scalar(select(SomeTable))
    assert row
    assert row.name == "NAME 1"


You can use the text construct to declare an expression within an index declaration, like text("""lower(replace(name, ' ', ''))""").
An example script would look like this:
import contextlib

import sqlalchemy as sa
from sqlalchemy.exc import IntegrityError

metadata = sa.MetaData()
tbl = sa.Table(
    't79227338',
    metadata,
    sa.Column('country', sa.String, nullable=False),
    sa.Column('organisation', sa.String, nullable=False),
    sa.Column('name', sa.String, nullable=False),
    sa.Index(
        'uq_country_orgid_lower_trim_name',
        'country',
        'organisation',
        sa.text("""lower(replace(name, ' ', ''))"""),
        unique=True,
    ),
)

engine = sa.create_engine('postgresql+psycopg2:///so', echo=True)
metadata.drop_all(engine)
metadata.create_all(engine)

names = ['Name 1', 'name1', 'nAmE 1', ' naME 1 ']
values = [
    {'country': 'Ruritania', 'organisation': 'Palace Guard', 'name': n} for n in names
]

for vals in values:
    with contextlib.suppress(IntegrityError):
        with engine.begin() as conn:
            conn.execute(tbl.insert().values(**vals))

with engine.connect() as conn:
    rows = conn.execute(sa.select(tbl)).all()

    assert len(rows) == 1
    assert rows[0].name == 'Name 1'

This is the generated index DDL:
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX uq_country_orgid_lower_trim_name 
  ON t79227338 (country, organisation, lower(replace(name, ' ', '')))

Using the information from this answer we can see that the index contains this data:
b'\x15Ruritania\x1bPalace Guard\rname1\x00\x00\x00'

showing that the indexed name is indeed lower-cased and free of spaces.

Resources

SQLAlchemy - Defining Constraints and Indexes
PostgreSQL - Indexes


Is the only reason here for using a unique index (not a unique constraint) the lack of SQLA's support for passing in functions in constraints?

@python_user Yes pretty much.

thanks, upvoted. slightly related, did you consider using func.lower(func.replace(column("name"), " ", "")) over the text version, any drawbacks to this?

There's a reference here to using text, though to be fair I didn't test the column approach.

it works, you beat me by an hour, or I would have posted it :)

https://pastebin.com/43vAv5pb in case you are interested

Feel free to post it, the OP may prefer ORM vs Core

I tend to avoid putting scripting this type requirement in SQLAlchemy (or any other obscurification [ORM] language). You cannot guarantee access will always be through that script. Rather direct ddl. One possibility is creating a generated column and a SQL function to create the single column for you index. This way you enforce the requirement at the lowest possible level thus ensuring it will always be employed. So, what is needed:

Define a function to create the value for the column.
Define a column as generated always as.
Define a unique index on the column.

As an example:
-- Assume an existing table defined as:  
create table test( id     integer generated always as identity
                                  primary key 
                , name    text 
                , country text
                , org_id  integer
                );

-- Now Define a function to create the value for the unique column/index.
create or replace function construct_ncoi( name_in    text
                                         , country_in text 
                                         , org_id_in  integer
                                         ) 
   returns text
   language sql 
   immutable 
as $$
   select lower(replace( concat(name_in, country_in, org_id_in::integer),' ','') );
$$; 

-- Create the generated column and define a unique index on it.
alter table test
    add ncoi    text generated always as ( construct_ncoi(name, country, org_id) ) stored;
alter table test
   add  constraint unique_noci unique (ncoi);

With the above your constraint is always enforced even if another team shares the data but chooses another ORM or the DBA attempts an emergency change via direct SQL. See Example Here.  
Yes, it is somewhat longer and makes the tradeoff of some storage for  the requirement of never being bypassed. (Well a superuser can get around it, but that is always possible.)

I think there may be a slight misunderstanding here? The OP is trying to generate a database-level constraint, albeit via having an ORM generating the DDL instead of writing it directly.

@snakecharmerb I fully understand that. I am suggesting that is not the better approach.

I'm curious - leaving ORMs aside, what's the benefit of this approach over defining an index or constraint directly via DDL?

Under normal conditions directly via DDL is desirable. But the generation expression must be declared as immutable, however,  concat() is not declared as immutable (stable?) so the full expression would be would not be immutable EITHER.  I slightly stretched the truth in the function declaration.
